Ionic ion-nav-link - how to access props in a component?
There is a component to which we can pass props via the componentProps. But the problem is, it is not clear how to access the passed props inside of that component (which ion-nav renders).
The documentation does not provide any example, and googling did not help either.
<ion-nav-link
      router-direction="forward"
      :component="searchComponent"
      componentProps="hello"
    >
      <button>OK</button>
    </ion-nav-link>

When ion-nav-link is opened, it will render searchComponent - but how to access the componentProps from the inside of searchComponent?
I googled the internet and did not find any solution, whatever I found was outdated (like, importing and using NavParams which is, apparently, no longer in the library)

You should mention you are using ionic-vue in the tag section. I was about to give an angular answer.
